# In C, what is the most efficient way to do math on a void* variable

Tags: c, type-conversion, void-pointers

Let's say I have a function like:

```
void myfunc(void* x, void* y){
   for(i=0; i<n;i++)
       y[i] = x[i]+1;
}
```

where my goal is to take vector `x`, do some math and store it in `y`. In this scenario I know `x` will be memory allocated as an array of `int`s.

I know we can't do math directly on `x` as it's cast as void, but I was curious about the most efficient way around this blocker. My current method is to `memcpy` x to an `int*` temp, do my math, then `memcpy` to `y`. Obviously this is not a particularly efficient process with multiple `memcpy`. I'm sure there is a better way, I just don't know enough about C memory allocation rules to figure it out.

Comment: If you know (or even just assume) that `x` will point into an array of `int`, then why are you declaring it as a `void *` instead of an `int *`?  Likewise for `y`?

Comment: the function is supposed to allow for int as well as double or other types

Comment: *If* the pointers passed as arguments are guaranteed to be `int*` then all you need is cast them to the correct type `*((int *)y + i) = *((int *)x + i) + 1;`. However, the behavior is undefined if the function gets called with pointers to something other than `int`.

Comment: But the function *doesn't* allow for other types, @JayDawahare, if it assumes that it is being applied to `int`s.  The function signature presented affords no mechanism for determining or communicating the data type.  The only way something like this supports multiple types is if someone who knows the type of the actual data selects a a function appropriate for that type.  In that case, it is the function signature that supports multiple types, not the function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the `memcpy`. If you wish to work with integers or bytes or whatever other type, then just do the appropriate casting, for example in case `x` and `y` refer to arrays of `int`:

```c
void myfunc(void* x, void* y){
   int *xp = x;
   int *yp = y;

   // By the way, what is n here? Maybe define it somewhere.
   for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
       yp[i] = xp[i] + 1;
}
```

And in such case, you don't really need to pass them as `void *` at all:

```c
void myfunc(int* x, int* y){
   // By the way, what is n here? Maybe define it somewhere.
   for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
       y[i] = x[i] + 1;
}
```

In general, `void *` is only useful when you do not care about the size and type of objects you are pointing to, or when you need to do generic operations depending on different sizes/types only known at runtime (still, always with appropriate casts).

If you want to allow different types, then you can do something like this:

```c
enum Type { INT, FLOAT, /* ... */ };

void myfunc(void* x, void* y, size_t n, enum Type t) {
    switch (t) {
        case INT: {
            int *xi = x;
            int *yi = y;

            for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
                yi[i] = xi[i] + 1;
            
            break;
        }

        case FLOAT: {
            float *xf = x;
            float *yf = y;

            for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
                yf[i] = xf[i] + 1;
            
            break;
        }

        // case ...: {
        // ...
        // }
    }
}
```

**Note that** this is not really good practice in C though. If you are able to know the type at compile time, then by all means just define different functions taking different types as arguments, it will be the fastest option.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the pointers point to arrays of `int`, you can convert to that type:

```
void myfunc(void* x, void* y){
   int *a = x;
   int *b = y;
   for(i=0; i<n;i++)
       b[i] = a[i]+1;
}
```